# Localized data in REST JSON responses

Tags: json, rest

We are currently designing a REST interface with localized data and are wondering what kind of approach to use to encode localized data.

The options we came up with are

l10n object child

```
{"id": 1, 
 "l10n": {"en": {"title": "English title"}, 
          "fi": {"title": "Suomalainen otsikko"}}
```

localized properties

```
{"id": 1, 
 "title": {"en": "English title", 
           "fi": "Suomalainen otsikko"}}
```

The first encoding is easier to merge, but the second approach is e.g. compatible with the localization encoding of JSON-LD.

Comment: Would it make more sense for the request to ask for a particular language instead of returning all languages?

Comment: i would prefer the second notation, it looks well structured (consistent) and simpler to use than the fist example.

Answer (score 3):

I think better to use subdirectories, for example

`http://server/en/users` for english
`> http://server/ru/users` for russian

Its better than give users info in different language all the time